# In "multi hop" network, is computer => computer 0 hop or 1 hop?

Tags: routing

Would this here, a computer sending information directly to another computer, count as 0 hops or 1 hop?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As stated on [this](https://www.lifewire.com/what-are-hops-hop-counts-2625905) site:

> A hop is a computer networking term that refers to the number of routers that a packet (a portion of data) passes through from its source to its destination. Sometimes a hop is counted when a packet passes through other hardware on a network, like switches, access points, and repeaters. This isn't always the case and it depends on what role those devices are playing on the network and how they're configured.

So as there are no routers showed between the two workstations, I'd say this is a point-to-point connection (layer 2 link with only two devices) with no hops in between.